# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Capybara::ElementNotFound into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, capybara

I have some pretty basic code:

```
  def select_author_name(comment)
    selector = 'span.name'
    comment.find(selector).text
  rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
    Rails.logger.warn('Could not get author_name: ' + e)
    puts e
    ''
  end
```

When i run this code and successfully rescue a `Capybara::ElementNotFound` error it blows up with the following error:

`TypeError: no implicit conversion of Capybara::ElementNotFound into String`

The strange thing is that the `puts e` line will print out the error no problem.

My question is this:

Why would the concatenation attempt cause problems printing `e` when i can successfully print out `e` with `puts`?  Don't both of them result in a `.to_s` call under the covers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby actually uses the implicit `#to_str` method when concatenating strings, rather than `#to_s`.

In this case, the simplest solution is probably to change your code to:

`Rails.logger.warn('Could not get author_name: ' + e.to_s)`

If you want to avoid that for some reason, and would rather have all error objects behave as you expected when doing string concatenation in the future, you could also open up the `StandardError` class and define `to_str`:

```
class StandardError
  def to_str
    self.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: This explains the difference between `to_s` and `to_str`: http://marcgg.com/blog/2017/01/23/ruby-to-s-to-str/ .  Thank you for answering!